# How can I know if I have access to the device webcam

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access the camera of the device my unity program is working on. I know the app works when it has access, and have some error messages in case no cameras are detected, but I am running into an issue when the user does not allow me to access the device camera. Unity detects the cameras when I have access to them and when I don't have access to them. Only when I try to use the camera (with `backCam.Play();` where backCam is a `WebCamTexture` object) do I get any error about the issue, which reads: `ERROR - Could not find specified video device`

I tried to handle the issue by encasing `backCam.Play();` with a `try` and `catch` block, and set the catch argument to `Exception e` as I have read that this would catch all exceptions. When executed, this catch block does not trigger. I have also tried replacing `catch` with `finally` but it seems that `finally` triggers even if I have access to the camera, which is not what I want.

I have attempted to find any internal commands that can tell me if I have access to the camera with no luck. I have also been searching the online forums for a question similar to this with no luck.

I'm not very familiar with the c# and unity libraries so I may have missed something along the way.

Follow-up: It is possible that the reason my `try - catch` block doesn't work is due to `WebCamTexture` already catching this issue internally, and thus the external one defined by me is ignored. If this is the case, is there a way for me to detect this event at all?

Comment: What about trying to get 1st frame from the camera, if you don't have access to it, it should throw an exception at that point and you can handle that?

Comment: Isn't that what happens when I try to use `backCam.Play();`?

Comment: Try-catch may fail here if the C# code can't catch errors from native code, so WebCamTexture.Play() may interface with code for whatever platform it runs on. Unfortunately, as you have mentioned, this is problematic, as you have no way of knowing if the camera will work until you try. Even if you can verify that you have permission, it will fail if another app is already using that camera. Probably needs to be reported to Unity, as there are no methods or properties to check first and you can't try-catch it.

Comment: This actually seems like the best course of action. Would you like to make a reply, instead of a comment, for me to mark as the answer @johnfernow?

Comment: Thanks @Divinor. If in the future I see Unity adds new methods or properties to check for, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I know this is sometime later, have you tried the method documented here?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-isPlaying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue today and have sorted out a 2-step handy work-around for anyone coming across this in future.

[@derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) is correct in saying the try-catch wont help, Unity is not throwing a catchable exception for this issue:

> If the error is not thrown as exception but rather a "normal"
> Debug.LogError Unity creates, then a try - catch won't help, no.

So with try-catch not workable a solution here, I found we instead need to add a simple log handler to look over the logs and manually decided to pause or not. This solution means we can basically custom 'catch' and check *all* errors being thrown - choosing to ignore the webcam error. But we still get Unity to pause for any other errors/exceptions as Unity usually would with 'Error Pause' enabled (as it is by default).

**Step 1- Disable 'Error Pause'**

This is a button in the Unity console area, just above where your debug logs and errors print. Disabling this means Unity wont pause for *any* errors. We need to next add a script which will let us control the pausing functionality ourselves.

**Step 2- The Log Handler**

Heres the log handler C# script I threw together, based on [this unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html). Create 'LogHandler.cs' with the code below, and put it on an empty object (I just called this 'LogHandler') in the scene so it runs with your game:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class LogHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string output = "";
    public string stack = "";

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
    }
    
    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        output = logString;
        stack = stackTrace;

        //Check if incoming log is an ERROR or EXCEPTION
        if(type == LogType.Error || type == LogType.Exception) {
            //Catch our custom webcam error (add more here if needed)
            if (output == "ERROR - Could not find specified video device") {
                Debug.Log("Caught a custom webcam error! [Not Pausing]");
                //trigger anything custom for the error here, like printing error text to the screen or something  
                //otherwise this will ignore and not pause - as we want
            } else {
                //debug pause as normal for all other errors
                Debug.Break();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

That should do it!

Unity will ignore this webcam device issue and keep running. Any other errors or exceptions and Unity will still pause via the Default.Break() in the LogHandler. You can also add in any other errors you want to ignore. And I added a custom option in the 'HandleLog()' function which adds some red text to the scene displaying *'ERROR WebCam Device Not Avaliable'* - so even though Unity now ignores the error, you still get some visual feedback that the error has been triggered (which will explain to the user why no webcam video is playing).

Hope this helps someone. Not an intuitive problem, and a pretty hackish solution - but it works for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

`Try-catch` may fail here if the C# code can't catch errors from native code, so `WebCamTexture.Play()` may interface with code for whatever platform it runs on.

Unfortunately, as you have mentioned, this is problematic, as you have no way of knowing if the camera will work until you try. Even if you can verify that you have permission, it will fail if another app is already using that camera.

This probably needs to be reported to Unity, as there are no methods or properties to check to see if you can use a given camera and you can't `try-catch` it, meaning you have no certainty you will avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is not thrown as exception but rather a "normal" `Debug.LogError` Unity creates then a `try - catch` won't help, no.

And the exact purpose of [`finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) is that it runs **always** no matter if any `catch` block triggered before or not.

---

What you want to rather do is check the [`WebCamTexture.devices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-devices.html) first.

> Return a list of available devices.

If there are no available devices then you already know that it won't work.

```
private WebCamTexture webCam;

private void Awake()
{
    var devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    
    if(devices.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No webcam available!", this);
    }
    else
    {
        webCam = new WebCamTexture();
        // this basically equals
        //webCam = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name);
    }
}
```

Then later whenever doing something webcam related first check

```
if(webCam)
```

otherwise no webcam can be used.

Comment: I might not have made this clear enough in the post, I'll edit it in a bit accordingly. Even if I don't have access to the device camera, running the `WebCamTexture.devices` still fills my devices array with cameras (which I do not have access to). Similar to you, I also have an `if` where I check the size of the array. Additionally, I have tried the `if(webCam)` but no dice, the if is still triggered even if I don't have access to the camera

Comment: Could you run a test and print out the name of all "available" devices .... I think this might be related to the name of the device not provided like e.g. here [How do I access a webcam if Unity won't report its name?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1523955/how-do-i-access-a-webcam-if-unity-wont-report-its.html) .. unfortunately there seems to be no real solution for this case since Unity goes by device name

Comment: The names of all devices in the `devices` array when given permission: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam, USB Camera. When permission is not given: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam, USB Camera. I had checked this before hoping the names would be null